# cufon help embedding 2 fonts ignoring first rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cufon

I am currently try and cufon to lots of text on my website, however when I implement Cufon on the second cufon.register() seems to fire and it overwrites the first, my code looks like below

```
Cufon.replace('nav a, h1', {"font-family":"Typewriter"}); // Works without a selector engine
Cufon.replace('p', {"font-family":"Segoe Print"}); // Works without a selector engine
```

Comment: What does "I am currently try and cufon" mean?

Comment: If you want to replace everything, just use Cufon.replace('body');

Answer (score 0):

refresh your cufon by

```
Cufon.refresh('nav a, h1');
```